# Create columns taking successive values from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition-by

| date | message | rnk_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-19 10:48:51 | mess1 | 8 |
| 2022-12-19 10:57:13 | mess2 | 8 |
| 2022-12-19 10:57:23 | mess3 | 8 |
| 2022-12-19 10:57:49 | mess4 | 8 |
| 2022-12-19 10:57:58 | mess5 | 8 |
| 2022-12-19 10:58:07 | mess6 | 8 |
| 2022-12-19 11:00:36 | mess7 | 8 |
| 2023-02-06 11:17:55 | mess1 | 5 |
| 2023-02-06 11:18:02 | mess2 | 5 |
| 2023-02-06 11:20:08 | mess3 | 5 |
| 2023-02-06 11:20:19 | mess4 | 5 |
| 2023-02-06 11:20:37 | mess5 | 5 |
| 2023-02-06 11:20:40 | mess6 | 5 |
| 2023-02-06 11:22:12 | mess7 | 5 |

each new column must take the value of the date corresponding to the message and reproduce it for each rnk_id group.

Each new column mess1, mess2, mess3, etc... takes the value of the column message. For column 1, I take the date that corresponds to mess1 (2022-12-19 10:48:51.5470000) and I copy it for each group rnk_id, for the second column I take the value mess 2 and I take the date of mess2 (2022-12-19 10:57:13.4230000) and I copy it for each group rnk_id... and so on

expected output :

| date | message | rnk_id | mess1 | mess2 | mess3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-19 10:48:51 | mess1 | 8 | 2022-12-19 10:48:51 | 2022-12-19 10:57:13 | 2022-12-19 10:57:23 |
| 2022-12-19 10:57:13 | mess2 | 8 | 2022-12-19 10:48:51 | 2022-12-19 10:57:13 | 2022-12-19 10:57:23 |
| 2022-12-19 10:57:23 | mess3 | 8 | 2022-12-19 10:48:51 | 2022-12-19 10:57:13 | 2022-12-19 10:57:23 |
| 2022-12-19 10:57:49 | mess4 | 8 | 2022-12-19 10:48:51 | 2022-12-19 10:57:13 | 2022-12-19 10:57:23 |
| 2022-12-19 10:57:58 | mess5 | 8 | 2022-12-19 10:48:51 | 2022-12-19 10:57:13 | 2022-12-19 10:57:23 |
| 2022-12-19 10:58:07 | mess6 | 8 | 2022-12-19 10:48:51 | 2022-12-19 10:57:13 | 2022-12-19 10:57:23 |
| 2022-12-19 11:00:36 | mess7 | 8 | 2022-12-19 10:48:51 | 2022-12-19 10:57:13 | 2022-12-19 10:57:23 |
| 2023-02-06 11:17:55 | mess1 | 5 | 2023-02-06 11:17:55 | 2023-02-06 11:18:02 | 2023-02-06 11:20:08 |
| 2023-02-06 11:18:02 | mess2 | 5 | 2023-02-06 11:17:55 | 2023-02-06 11:18:02 | 2023-02-06 11:20:08 |
| 2023-02-06 11:20:08 | mess3 | 5 | 2023-02-06 11:17:55 | 2023-02-06 11:18:02 | 2023-02-06 11:20:08 |
| 2023-02-06 11:20:19 | mess4 | 5 | 2023-02-06 11:17:55 | 2023-02-06 11:18:02 | 2023-02-06 11:20:08 |
| 2023-02-06 11:20:37 | mess5 | 5 | 2023-02-06 11:17:55 | 2023-02-06 11:18:02 | 2023-02-06 11:20:08 |
| 2023-02-06 11:20:40 | mess6 | 5 | 2023-02-06 11:17:55 | 2023-02-06 11:18:02 | 2023-02-06 11:20:08 |
| 2023-02-06 11:22:12 | mess7 | 5 | 2023-02-06 11:17:55 | 2023-02-06 11:18:02 | 2023-02-06 11:20:08 |

for the first column no worries:
`first_value(date) OVER (PARTITION BY rnk_id ORDER BY date) as mess1`

I am unable to use the ROWS Clause to achieve this

Comment: I have read this a few times and I can't for the life of me figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is the "ROWS clause"? Do you mean by limiting the window with something like `ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEEDING AND CURRENT ROW`?

Comment: Could you just add full expected output, with some more explanation?

Comment: This question is hard to understand.  Here are some hints how to make it clearer:  For a column with a date in it (the first column) make the dates different.  Having all the same day with just different seconds or mili-seconds makes it very hard to compare and understand expected output.   The same is true for rnk_id -- unless the expectation is they are all the same make them different so we can see how that data impacts the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `cte` and using `first_value()` and `lead()` we get the first row correctly then we spread this row over all the rows :

```
with cte as (
      select t.*, 
        first_value(case when message = 'mess1' then date end)
          over (partition by rnk_id order by date) as mess1,
        lead(date)
          over (partition by rnk_id order by date) as mess2,
        lead(date,2)
          over (partition by rnk_id order by date) as mess3
      from mytable t
    )
    select date, message, rnk_id, mess1,
      first_value(mess2) over (partition by rnk_id order by date) as mess2,
      first_value(mess3) over (partition by rnk_id order by date) as mess3
    from cte
    order by rnk_id desc
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/s4CLoQ9m)

Answer (score -1):

You could pivot it but you lose the leading date and message columns in the result.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_lWLstcC)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT rnk_id,
         message,
         _date
    FROM mess
) src
PIVOT
(
    MAX(_date)
    FOR message IN (
        [mess1],
        [mess2],
        [mess3],
        [mess4],
        [mess5],
        [mess6],
        [mess7])
) pvt
```

Result

| rnk_id | mess1 | mess2 | mess3 | mess4 | mess5 | mess6 | mess7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2022-12-19 11:17:55.2360000 | 2022-12-19 11:18:02.6220000 | 2022-12-19 11:20:08.4910000 | 2022-12-19 11:20:19.2010000 | 2022-12-19 11:20:37.1190000 | 2022-12-19 11:20:40.2950000 | 2022-12-19 11:22:12.6280000 |
| 8 | 2022-12-19 10:48:51.5470000 | 2022-12-19 10:57:13.4230000 | 2022-12-19 10:57:23.6540000 | 2022-12-19 10:57:49.1290000 | 2022-12-19 10:57:58.0850000 | 2022-12-19 10:58:07.0980000 | 2022-12-19 11:00:36.0690000 |

Comment: unfortunately this is not the result I'm looking for, it's more like this but I can't manage to do it for intermediate values. https://dbfiddle.uk/wu9yAfy5 SELECT *
  ,first_value(_date) OVER (PARTITION BY rnk_id ORDER BY _date) as mess1
  ,first_value(_date) OVER (PARTITION BY rnk_id ORDER BY _date DESC) as mess7
FROM mess
ORDER BY _date ASC